# Data not saving in database. Laravel with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm having an issue "new for me" since i was able to store the data in database but now i can't. I'm passing some fields through ajax and it was working good but now it isn't.

Here's my controller code:

```
public function update_os(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
      'os' => 'required|max:50'
    ]);
    $user = User::find(Auth::id());
    $user->fill([
      'os' => $request->os
    ]);
    return response()->json($user);
}
```

Now this is my ajax code:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#AjaxFormOs', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var os = $('#AjaxFormOs').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: userUrl + 'updateos',
        data: os,
        _token: token,
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function (operative) {
        toastr.info("Your new OS is: " + operative.os + "", 'You have been updated your OS info.', {timeOut: 5000});
        $('#os-cancel').addClass('hide');
        $('#os').addClass('hide');
        $('#user-os').removeClass('hide');
        $('.user-info-content').find('#user-os').html(operative.os);
        $('#os-edit').removeClass('hide');
    });
});
```

This is the route:

```
Route::post('/{username}/updateos', 'Account\ProfileController@update_os');
```

This is the form:

```
<form id="AjaxFormOs">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <ul class="list-inline p-r-10 user-info-details-form">
        <li><strong>OS</strong></li>
        <li class="m-l-20 p-b-10" id="user-os">{{ $user->os }}</li>
        <li>
            <input id="os" type="text" class="form-control hide user-input-field" name="os" value="{{ $user->os }}" autofocus>
            <button type="submit" class="hide"></button>
        </li>
        <li class="pull-right"><a href="#" id="os-edit">Edit</a></li>
        <li class="pull-right"><a class="hide" href="#" id="os-cancel">Cancel</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

This is the response "from google chrome developer tools"

```
Request URL: http://centralgeek.test/9/updateos
Status Code: 200 OK

{id: 9, name: "José", last_name: "Martínez", username: "josem", 
gender: "Hombre", os: "Ubuntu",…}
about: null
background: "def-background.jpg"
city: "Curicó"
country: "Venezuela"
created_at: "2018-10-09 00:32:45"
deleted_at: null
email: "josem@app.com"
gender: "Hombre"
id: 9
job_title: "¿A qué te dedicas?."
last_login_at: "2018-10-09 00:32:45"
last_login_ip: "127.0.0.1"
last_name: "Martínez"
name: "José"
os: "Ubuntu"
phone_model: null
profilepic: "default.png"
twitter: null
twitter_link: null
updated_at: "2018-10-09 01:21:41"
user_agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
username: "josem"
```

As you can see there the os data i've passed is "ubuntu" but once i refresh de window that info disappear.. Is not storing it on database, but it was working before. So what's happening?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about you do some debugging and figure out if the problem is Javascript or PHP? Then you could cut the amount of code in your question in half.

Comment: you could also try Auth::user() instead of User::find(Auth::id())

Answer (score 2):

You have only filled the `user` instance with new data.

```
$user->fill([
  'os' => $request->os
]);
```

But has not saved to the database.

```
$user->save();
```

**Alternative**

An alternative to both this `fill()` and `save()` function combination,
You can use update.

```
$user->update([
    'os' => $request->os
]);
```

Comment: Actually i notice that 10 minutes ago, thank you for your answer, finally works again.